# How to?: Flutter RaisedButton onPressed opens a Form

Tags: flutter

Flutter:
I would like to open a Form after a RaisedButton is pressed. How do I have to compose the onPressed function of the RaisedButton to achieve this?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Read the documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#forms) and refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) instruction before asking any question on SO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned more detail, i hope you need something to show or input. You can use `showBottomSheet` to fulfill this like this :

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc) {
        return Container(
          child: Text('Implement your form here')
        );
    });
  },
  child: Text('BottomSheet Demo')
)
```